# useSelector will not display updated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, redux, react-redux

I am absolutely beating my head against this. I am fairly new to Redux and I need some guidance. I am simply trying to add a new 'post' and display it in a list. When I add a post, it indeed works. However it will only display it once I reload the page.

I have tried useEffect, I have tried store.getState(). I am very stuck. I have also examined the store object and can verify that the data structure is correct.

When a new post is created, I create a copy of the post and rename it to the length of posts. I know that is odd but that is the use-case.

I've had to rename things in this sample.

```
function MyComponent() {
    const posts = useSelector((state: any) => state.post.posts)
    const [postSelection, setPostSelection] = useState<string>(posts[0].name)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const create_action_creator = bindActionCreators(create_post, dispatch)
    const delete_action_creator = bindActionCreators(delete_post, dispatch)

    const handleCreateNewPost = async () => {
        let postToCopy = posts.filter((post: Post) => post.name === postSelection)[0]
        postToCopy.name = `${postToCopy.name} ${posts.length}`
        // We should not be setting the new post to default
        postToCopy.is_default = false
        create_action_creator(postToCopy)
    }

return (
<Button 
   onClick={handleCreateNewPost} 
   variant="contained" 
   style={{width: '100%', marginLeft: '2%'}}>Create New Post</Button>
            {posts.map((post: Post) => 
                <div>
                    {post.name}
                </div>
            )})
}
```

My action creator:

```
export const create_post = (post: Post) => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<PostAction>) => {
    return axios.post('/api/post/', post)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type: PostActions.CREATE,
          payload: response.data
        })
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: So you are dispatching `PostActions.CREATE` action and you want the UI to select an "updated" `state.post.posts` value? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve]? Also just FYI, you are mutating the Redux state in your `handleCreateNewPost` handler. I don't know if that's related to your issue, but since we can't see what your reducers do to state it's hard to say why state isn't updating as you expect.

Comment: Please be aware that you're using a pre-2019 style of Redux that's multiple times the amount of code you'd write in modern Redux instead.
You are very likely following an outdated tutorial that on top of everything teaches you non-standard patterns like `bindActionCreators`.
Please follow the official Redux tutorial, it will also show you better ways to fetch data.
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: That said, without seeing your reducer (which is most likely the source of your error), nobody will be able to help you here.

Comment: Also, your `postToCopy` is not a copy, it's a reference to the actual value in the Redux store. That's strictly forbidden. Please update to modern patterns, they would warn you about errors like this.

Comment: I fixed the ```postToCopy``` by changing it to ```Object.assign({}, post)```. As I went to post the reducer, I found my error. This was an inherited codebase and it was originally setup to only account for 1 post. Once again, I know that sounds odd but it is a very specific use case. I fixed that and got it working. Good to know about it being an older version of Redux. Sadly with the time contraints I'm under currently I'm not going to be able to update/upgrade Redux for a while. Thank you for the help, sorry I didn't think to check the reducers first! Redux is confusing.